# Java Background help needed

Tags: java, input, background, applet, scroll

I have been banging my head over a couple of issues regarding my background and hope that you guys could shed some light on my problems or point out where I am failing. This isn't an attempt to get others to do my project for me, but rather that I have tried and not been able to resolve the problems myself. I have included all my source code in this post and would greatly appreciate any help that I can get. My issues are as follows....

1. I have set my applet window at 800 x 480, and backgroung image at 1800 x 1160. I have also set boundaries on all sides to stop my player from going beyond my background. When I do hit the edges
   of the game screen my character does stop as planned (in all directions). However, when I tap two directional keys at the same time to create diagonal motion the player hits the corners of the game play screen and exits the playing area and then bounces back. Why is this happening and how do I stop it from doing so?
2. Whilst moving the character left, right, up or down, I have noticed a slight glitch. When the character hits the edge of the applet window (800 or 480) the screen then begins t scrolls as expected, but I noticed that the character briefly speeds up as the now vosible background comes into view. I am struggling to properly set up my project and hoping that somebody could direct me the right way.

Comment: are you developing a game? what engine are you using?
try again to include your sources into the question. Without the code we are nearly unable to help you

Comment: Yes I am trying to make a game, its not something I wish to create with perfection, only to get an understanding. I am not using an engine I would like.to try and build it slowly by learning all stages step by step.

Comment: Hey guys,  I have now uploaded my source code @ www.daryl.comeze.com